# php eval function

Tags: php

How to know that eval() is disabled or enabled in the web server.What is the php code to know this?Whether there is any php code to enable it , if it is disabled on the server?

Comment: eval("echo 'Hello World!';"); 
There you go.

Comment: The typical safe_mode restrictions affect `exec` and co. But `eval` is not usually blocked. And anyway you could just work around it by using `include(..file_put_contents("tmp", ...))` - so there really is no point for hosters to disable it.

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing built into PHP which lets you disable eval (unlike other functions which you can disable).

However, you can install a security path for PHP called Suhosin, which lets you disable eval, and also adds other security features to PHP.

http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.executor.disable_eval

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with you as [`eval` is a language construct](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php#refsect1-function.eval-notes). If this is the only way to disable `eval`, it could be checked for with [`ini_get`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php).

Answer (score 5):

<strike>You should be able to determine if `eval()` exists with:</strike>

http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php

```
if (function_exists('eval')) {
    echo "eval() exists, it does it does!";
}
```

**EDIT**

Actually, `eval()` is a language construct so it can't be tested using `function_exists()`. However, this should work:

```
<?php

$isevalfunctionavailable = false;

$evalcheck = "\$isevalfunctionavailable = true;";

eval($evalcheck);

if ($isevalfunctionavailable === true) {
    echo "\$isevalfunctionavailable is true.\n";
    echo var_dump($isevalfunctionavailable);
}

?>
```

http://codepad.org/6xg2tO1K

Comment: This will always fail, because `eval` is a language construct. It's like testing for `function_exists("foreach")`

Comment: I'm not sure. It might just generate a fatal error rather if you test with `Eval()`. You cannot catch those. What you could potentially do is `create_function("", "eval('test');")` without invoking it. This would generate a non-fatal error I believe.

Comment: Hmm, that's a great point. Too bad you can't test for `eval()` with `function_exists()`.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, as said, `eval` is unlikely to be disabled. But just in case, there are three workarounds:

```
$eval = create_function("", "$code");
$eval();
```

Or even just:

```
assert_options(ASSERT_ACTIVE, 1);   
assert_options(ASSERT_QUIET_EVAL, 1);
assert("$code");
```

And the filesystem-workarounds:

```
file_put_contents($tmp=tempnam("/tmp", "EVAL"), "$code");
include($tmp);
```

All work equivalent to a straight eval.

Comment: Last one work for me but I had to replace "$code" with "<?php $code ?>"